# How do I redirect a flask webpage based on a POST from another application?

Tags: python, post, flask, python-requests

I'm attempting to redirect a webpage based on a POST from another running python application.  What is restricting the redirect line from running on the server? The print statement writes to the console sucessfully. Also, it's worth noting that I will not necessarily be on this webpage when the POST request comes through but I'd like to force the server to render that page.  I've also tried to use render_template with no luck.

In my main flask application:

```
@blueprint.route('/my_route', methods=['GET','POST')
#@login_required # I had to uncomment this in order for it work
def my_route():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.args.get('my_data')
        print(data)

    return redirect(url_for('mypath_blueprint.my_route'))
```

From my other application (or POSTMAN if you like)

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://my_ip_address:5000/mypath/my_route', data={'my_data':1}, allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: check `print( url_for('mypath_blueprint.my_route') )` - maybe you redirect to the same url. You can also try some external url like `redirect('https://stackoverflow')` to see if it will redirect you to stackoverflow.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to redirect a specific client to a webpage served by your flask app, triggered by a post request done by a different application to your flask app?

Comment: @gittert, yes that is correct

Comment: @furas, the print is showing the proper path: /mypath/my_route.  Also, it seems like what is happening is that the view is redirecting the client making the POST (ie. my external application) not the client logged in to the Flask server.  When using an external URL, POSTMAN displays the HTML from my redirected website (google.com in my example).  This leads me to believe that I'm going about this the incorrect way or what I'm trying is not conventional.

Comment: one client (external program) can't redirect other clients. It could only change settings in Flask and when other client will load this paga again then flask can use different url from settings to redirect client.

Comment: @furas, I had a feeling this might be the case.  I will change my code to have clients check for Flask changes.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

instead of printing data redirect user with the data

```
@blueprint.route('/my_route', methods=['GET','POST')
#@login_required # I had to uncomment this in order for it work
def my_route():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.args.get('my_data')
        return redirect(url_for('mypath_blueprint.my_route', data=data))

    return render_template("mypath_blueprint.my_route")
```

to see if you are being redirected print out status code

`print(r.history)`

if 302 means URL redirection